# How to create raw string literal with quote?

Tags: freemarker

How do I create a raw String literal that contains quotes?

Documentation says that:

```
${r"${foo}"}
```

will print out:

```
${foo}
```

But what I need is to print out:

```
${foo"bar"}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `<#assign test = "$" + "{foo\"bar\"}" />`? change the outside quotes to single if you don't want to use the `\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't escape the quote in a raw string literal, but you have two kind of quotes to chose from (`"` and `'`), so in this case you could write `${r'${foo"bar"}'}`. If you are unlucky and you need both kind of quotes inside the raw string literal, then you will have to use a normal string literal with `\` escapes, like `\{`.

(Note that in case you have a lot of `${}`-s  that FreeMarker shouldn't interpret, then maybe you should set the `interpolation_syntax` configuration setting to `square_bracket`, so that `${}` is not special for FreeMarker anymore.)